# Why my CSV with JSONL doesn´t have Labels for training AutoML?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket, google-cloud-automl

I have a problem with my CSV that is created using python. I'm following the example of google cloud about how to create JSONL from my PDF files, the big problem is that I can make my CSV with JSONL URL'S form my PDF files but this JSONL doesn't have any label. I'm using this file ->
**input_helper_v2.py** to create my CSV with JSONL, after that when I upload my CSV to google cloud for train my AutoML I got this error:

[image]

I tried to put some labels by myself in the CSV but that doesn't work. I don´t know if maybe its not the correct way to do this but I can find any solutions

This is an example of my CSV without labels:

[image]

Comment: Can you share what command you executed when you run `input_helper_v2.py`? It will also help us if you share a sample unprocessed file.

Comment: Sure, this is the coman that I used to run input_helper_v2.py:

python2 input_helper_v2.py -t gs://Mybucket/prueba gs://Mybucket/Induccion/Acuerdos/*.pdf gs://Mybucket/Induccion/Acuses/*.pdf

Comment: Have you tried removing the spaces in your csv file, making this [sample CSV](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare#csv) as a pattern?